# TransactionScope and multiple EF contexts across multiple method calls

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions, transactionscope

Given the following code, the methods `DoDatabaseOperation()` and `MethodAnotherContext()` will be included in the transaction? Note that `context1` and `context2` are of same type and working on the connection string.

```
using (EFContext context1 = new EFContext())
{
  using (TransactionScope transScope = new TransactionScope())
  {
          DoDatabaseOperation(context1);  // Call context1.functionImport to update records
          while (....) 
          {
              .................A lot of code............
              context1.SaveChanges();              
              MethodAnotherContext();          
          }
          transScope.complete();
   }
}

public void MethodAnotherContext()
    using (EFContext context2 = new EFContext())
    {
        ......................
        context2.SaveChanges();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connections on identical connection strings that are opened within the lifetime of a `TransactionScope` will be enlisted in the same 'simple' transaction ('simple' means: without the need of a distributed transaction coordinator). EF contexts by default only open connections when database interaction is actually needed and close them afterwards. They do not open a connection when they are created.

So the first time a connection is opened — and closed — is in `DoDatabaseOperation`. Then, in `SaveChanges` and `MethodAnotherContext`, more connections are opened and closed, all within the scope of the `TransactionScope`. Finally, `transScope.complete();` commits all changes.

Comment: please Verify that I understand your answer, you are saying "Yes", if those methods are accessing the same database (same connection string), then all of them will be in the same transaction.